# get() method in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

According to get() method it returns the string or characters exists in between the specified range between `startindex` and `endindex` of the method. But here the problem exists because i am not able to get the string existing between the specified range**

**Here is the code:**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
txt = Text(root, spacing3 = 100, width = 50)
txt.insert('0.1',"My name is Abhishek Bhardwaj")
txt.pack()

#get() method of text widget
x = txt.get('5.7')            **** This is a problem ****      
print(x)                      **** This is a problem **** 

root.mainloop()
```

In the output of given program there is no desired output coming. It means there is no string in the output from get() method

How to get desired output from the program by using get() method with parameters For eg: - `get('5.7')`

Comment: try this **x = txt.get('1.0',END)[:-1]**

get() method has two important parameters start, end indices and each
Indices are either keywords or 'x.y' where x is line number and y is word number

Comment: You have a single line of text, so `txt.get('5.7')` returns `''` as it should since there is no text at line 5. By the way, index '0.1' is not correct though tkinter does not raise an error, lines are numbered starting to 1 so you probably meant `txt.insert('1.0',"My name is Abhishek Bhardwaj")`

Comment: @RahulARanger y is the character number not the word number.

Comment: @scotty3785 yes ,my bad I made a mistake there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things to note here -

- `txt.insert('0.1', ....)` -> this 0.1 is not a valid index (It does work though, but use '1.0' which means *put this text in line 1, character position 0* - simply meaning start of the text widget). The index need to be either a constant (like `tk.END` - `tk` is `tkinter` here), or a value in form `x.y` where x being the line number, y being the character position number ON THAT LINE.
- `txt.get('5.7')` will always return `''` - an empty string . Because this translates to *Get the text at line 5, char position 7*. There is no line 5 in your text widget.

## The tk.Text.get() Method

Methods definition is `.get(index1, index2=None)`  (`index2` is not `inclusive` in the result which means the text returned will not include the character exactly at the `index2` position)
This method takes two important arguments. `index1` and `index2` - `index1` acting like `startindex` and `index2` acting like `endindex`. Each of these indices need to be either a constant (like `tk.END`) or a value in `x.y` form (as described above).

If you pass in both arguments let's say like `.get('x.y', 'p.q')`, it translates to - *get the text between line x, character number y AND line p. character number q*

If you do something like `.get('x.y', tk.END)` - you can use `END` here instead of `tk.END` because you used global import on tkinter - it translates to *get text between line x, character number y AND end of the text widget*

which means using `.get('1.0', tk.END)` return the complete text of widget.

But if you omit `index2` or `endindex`, it will default to `None` as in `.get(index1, index2=None)`. so
`txt.get('1.3')` will translate to `txt.get(index1='1.3', index2=None)`, returning only `'n'` from the sentence at line 1, character position 3.

Your code modified :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
txt = Text(root, spacing3 = 100, width = 50)
txt.insert('1.0', "My name is Abhishek Bhardwaj")
txt.pack()

#get() method of text widget
x = txt.get('1.0', '1.5') # 1.3 is in form x.y where x being line number and y being char number ON THAT LINE
print(x)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this `x.y` support only for `Text` or for `Entry` too?

Comment: @CoolCloud My initial guess is No. `tk.Entry` does support indexing (like 0, 1, 2...) or keywords (like `tk.END`), but there are no multiple lines in `Entry` widgets. So not `x.y` but just `x` where` x` being the index number or character position. Moreover the `.get()` method for `tk.Entry` does not accept any arguments. So the options I talked about are for `.delete()` and other methods.

Comment: `tk.END` isn't a _keyword_, it's a constant.

Comment: Oh right. Edited @Bryan. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You explained it verry well. Thanks and Regards Mr @P S Solanki